# yarn add installs multiple versions, [how to] ensure that there is only one installed?

Tags: yarnpkg, polkadot

I am trying to run [this tutorial](https://evmdocs.acala.network/tutorials/hardhat-tutorials/helloworld-tutorial) and I am getting a slew of warnings about conflicting packages (please see below).  When I run `yarn dedupe` I get a frustrating message `error The dedupe command isn't necessary. yarn install will already dedupe.`  First of all `yard install` has been replaced with `yarn add` and second, if yarn is automatically deduping, how come I have so many duplicate packages?  Can someone please tell this newbie how to fix these duplicate packages?  Do I have to manually go folder by folder and delete them?

```
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\types-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\types-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\types-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto
@polkadot/wasm-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 4.6.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\wasm-crypto
        cjs 5.1.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\node_modules\@polkadot\wasm-crypto
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\types-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/util-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto
@polkadot/wasm-crypto has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 4.6.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\wasm-crypto
        cjs 5.1.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util-crypto\node_modules\@polkadot\wasm-crypto
        cjs 4.6.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\wasm-crypto
@polkadot/util has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\api-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\types-augment\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-transactions\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.4.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@polkadot\util
        cjs 8.7.1       D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@open-web3\orml-api-derive\node_modules\@polkadot\util
@polkadot/rpc-core has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 7.11.1      D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\api-derive\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-core
        cjs 7.15.1      D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@open-web3\orml-api-derive\node_modules\@polkadot\rpc-core
@polkadot/types has multiple versions, ensure that there is only one installed.
Either remove and explicitly install matching versions or dedupe using your package manager.
The following conflicting packages were found:
        cjs 7.11.1      D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@polkadot\api-derive\node_modules\@polkadot\types
        cjs 7.15.1      D:\acala_hardhat\hello-world\node_modules\@acala-network\eth-providers\node_modules\@open-web3\orml-api-derive\node_modules\@polkadot\types
```

Answer (score 0):

See here: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/2399/how-to-prevent-remove-duplicate-modules-and-mismatched-version-numbers-i-e

Set your polkadot resolutions to the same values as [polkadot apps](https://github.com/polkadot-js/apps/blob/master/package.json) and you should be good to go. This is what they're currently set to:

Note: I also had to change my dependencies to match those versions, but the console is much cleaner now.